# Form with Multiple Inputs from multiple users

Tags: email, custom-form, form, multiple-values

I need to create a form with the following requirements:

1. Needs to be able to accept multiple inputs from multiple users.
2. Save as a draft while other users are still filling form throughout the day
3. Once all fields are filled, a submissions saves forms and emails results

I kind of have an idea for #3 but not sure about #1/#2.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this before with InfoPath and a workflow, but I think you want multiple users to fill out the form at the same time which is something that I have not done.  In the past I've setup an infopath form to only display the fields that need to be filled out by that user, then have a workflow at increments the infopath form to the next view and sends the link to the form to the next filler / approver.  This works great, but only allows for one person to add to their part of the form at a time.  You can also accomplish this with a PowerApp and Flow.